# iPhone SDK simple alert message question

Tags: iphone, sdk, simulator

```
char asd='a';
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure?" message:asd
               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

above code not compiling in iPhone simulator.
Why is that?
:)

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass a `char` where an `NSString` is expected. Read up on Objective-C and th Cocoa/Cocoa Touch documentation.

To fix your issue, try this:

```
NSString *asd = @"a";
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure?" message:asd
               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't compile *in* the iPhone
   simulator, you compile on your mac.
2. Do you get an error message?
3. The message parameter should be an `NSString`, not a `char`?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
char asd='a';
```

With

```
NSString *asd=@"a";
```

It should compile after it...